# Showdown Markdown Editor: How to resize images to fit in with the content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, markdown, pagedown, showdown

I am trying to use **stack over flows** markdown editor [showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) by its Angularjs Module [ng-showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/ng-showdown)

Everything is going fine but the image that are getting included are in their actual/original size.

how to resize them to fit in the text?

Given below is a dummy that is showing the same problem.

Many thanks!!!

```html
<html ng-app="theShowdown">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.3.0/showdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-showdown/1.1.0/ng-showdown.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var theShowdown = angular.module('theShowdown', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ng-showdown']);

    theShowdown.config(function() {

    })

     theShowdown.controller('theMain', function($scope, $showdown) {

      $scope.mymarkdown = `**Hello** _Stackover Flow_ ![Showdown][sd-logo]

[sd-logo]: http://logz.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/stack-overflow-logo.png`;

      var htmlValue = $showdown.makeHtml($scope.mymarkdown)

    })
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="theMain">
  <p markdown-to-html="mymarkdown"></p>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="150" ng-model="mymarkdown"></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I do not understand why would anyone will give this question a *down vote*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Disclaimer:

I'm the current showdown's project leader.

---

As per [showdown's documentation](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown#valid-options):

> parseImgDimensions: (boolean) [default false] Enable support for setting image dimensions from within markdown syntax. Examples:
>
> ```
> ![foo](foo.jpg =100x80)     simple, assumes units are in px
> ![bar](bar.jpg =100x*)      sets the height to "auto"
> ![baz](baz.jpg =80%x5em)  Image with width of 80% and height of 5em
> ```

So you need to enable the option **parseImgDimensions** and then use the above syntax.

### Example

Passing options in the constructor:

```
var converter = new showdown.Converter({parseImgDimensions: true});
```

or

```
var converter = new showdown.Converter();
converter.setOption('parseImgDimensions', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a way

while declaring the URL for the link add `abc.png  =100x*` which will set the height to 100 and width will be auto calculated.